# Trying to understand the bridge pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, abstraction, bridge

I am trying to read design patterns and currently going thru Bridge Pattern.

It states that

**Decouple the functional abstraction from the implementation so that the two can vary independently**

I was going thru this example on this link
:
https://www.journaldev.com/1491/bridge-design-pattern-java
[image]

Could somebody explain me how this example to this bold statement?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note to anyone attempting an answer: It might help to also view the original class diagram, before applying to bridge pattern, in the same link above.

Comment: @Tim It will be great if you can attempt an answer explaining. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like bridge is a way to implement multiple inheritance through composition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bridge` is splitting the interface and implementation in multiple parts. In your example you'll get 2 different interfaces `Shape`, `Color`. They will generate their own class hierarchies and because they are independent they can both vary.

You'll end up with multiple shapes and multiple colors that can be combined at runtime. This is achieved using `composition` instead of `inheritance`. Each instance of a `Shape` needs an instance of a `Color` when it gets created and that's the way you get a **red triangle** or a **green pentagon** or any other combination of a `Shape` and a `Color`.

The hierarchies aren't tightly coupled and they only communicate at an interface level.